# visual studios cant find package i installed through pip

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[Visual Studio says I'm running Python 0.0 AND 3.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPvtz.png)

Visual Studio is unable to find a package. I am able to run it in cmd using python.
I have had this problem before, but can't remember how I fixed it. I think I'm using the wrong version of python, but if that is the problem I don't know how to fix it.

Edit: using `py -3.10 -m pip install package`, instead of just `pip install package` seems to have worked.

Comment: Did you Google for this?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

Check the version in cmd and then if it is something above 3.7 or so you are good to go else reinstall python and if you are on Windows then check the box at bottom of the installation window of python which says "Add pip to path" something like that

Now in the VS Code

Hit Ctrl+Shift+p to open command palette and in that search for python interpreter and change it to plain one or you may choose

[Select Python Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zceUt.png)

Answer (score 0):

*use the vscode console*
First of all to check the packages insatalled in python you have to use the pip freeze.

```
pip freeze
```

This will help you to find out if the required package which you've installed is on the list or not.
If it is not present use the same console for:-

```
pip install <packageName>
```

for eg.

```
pip install django
```

then check the list agian

Answer (score 0):

What I learned today:
The good old trick still does it.

1. install the package from Solution Explorer>Python Environments>"your chosen env"
2. right click > Manage python packages
3. install the package
4. Now .... exit Visual Studio
5. Start Visual Studio again and ... yes, your new packages are now found in your script!